# TIMESTAMP type in sqlite DB

Tags: iphone, datetime, core-data, timestamp

I am now building an iPhone app and it involves core data. One of the entities has an attribute with Date type, which effectively generates a column with TIMESTAMP type in the corresponding sqlite DB. The value looks something like `320928592.400471`

My question is... how can I convert ordinary datetime into the TIMESTAMP type? I would like to preload some static data to the DB. Therefore, I need to know how to store the data directly to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that number is the same number returned by NSDate's `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, i.e. seconds since 1 January 2001.

It might be easier to either populate the database on the first run of your program, or to generate the prefilled database and export it from your phone to include in the bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Just wonder if the reference date is in GMT?

Comment: Yes. The specific definition of the reference date is "the first instance [sic] of 1 January 2001, GMT", see [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have done a very simple computation and it looks fine. =]